# -Wall without -Wreturn-type

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

According to the GCC manual, the `-Wreturn-type` options is enabled with `-Wall`. However, I can't find a proper way to disable it while keeping the rest of `-Wall` enabled.

Consider this code:

```
func() {}
```

If compiled without warnings, no output is produced. Now, if I turn on `-Wall` the following lines will appear:

```
$ gcc fn.c -Wall
fn.c:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
fn.c: In function ‘func’:
fn.c:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Ok, all nice. Now, if compiled with `-Wreturn-type`, the same output is produced:

```
$ gcc fn.c -Wreturn-type
fn.c:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
fn.c: In function ‘func’:
fn.c:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

So, I conclude that `-Wreturn-type` is responsible for those warnings. But maybe it's not, or I'm doing something worse, as this was expected to produce no output:

```
$ gcc fn.c -Wall -Wno-return-type
fn.c:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
```

Is it possible to use `-Wall` but disable `-Wreturn-type` completely? Or maybe I'm missing another available option?

If it matters, I'm on Mac OS 10.7 (Darwin 11) with GCC 4.2.1 (strangely enough, compiled with LLVM :P)

Comment: Just to be "that guy," why not listen to the warnings and either declare your function(s) as void, or add return values to them?

Comment: No problem, indeed I missed that in the question. It happens that I'm working with old code, slowly being transformed, and would prefer a clean output form the compiler. It's not a big deal though, I'll certainly fix those soon. The real motivation to this question was to discover that if an option enables some warnings, why its negated version won't disable them?

Comment: Last time I dug into this issue deeply, I concluded that it's just not possible to disable a single warning in GCC while retaining -Wall.   An annoying shortcoming.

Comment: @Stabledog: Hmm, I was hoping not to hear this… Thanks for pointing it out, and if you have experience with it you should consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `-Wno-implicit-int` to disable that warning:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wno-return-type -Wno-implicit-int fn.c
```

However, this might cause other warnings that you might want to see to be disabled. For example, it'll suppress warning about a variable declared like so:

```
static x = 1;
```

Pick your poison.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was scanning the manual for a solution but missed this option; now I checked it and also noted that `-Wimplicit` appears to be a synonym. Maybe `-Wreturn-type` behind the scenes triggers `-Wimplicit-int`, but not its inverse?

Comment: Something like that I suppose. As much as users often hate error numbers, I really wish that GCC would spit out a number as part of the warning or error.  It would make searching for the enabling/disabling of particular diagnostics much easier, I think.